# Create / plot normal distribution from unique data and their occurrence in python

Tags: python, scipy

Want to create normal distribution plot from unique dataset with occurrences, as shown below. The snippet below does the job, but there could be a pythonic way to implement instead of just repeating the unique data multiple times.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

uniqueVals = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 11.0, 13.0, 15.0]
occurrences = [14989.0, 13386.0, 14419.0, 8368.0, 11019.0, 11573.0, 7989.0, 7170.0]

# Avoid this portion to create multiple occurrence of same data
# _________________________________
vals = []
for v, occr in list(zip(uniqueVals, occurrences)):
    for _ in range(int(occr)):
        vals.append(v)
# ------------------------------
mean = np.mean(vals)
sd = np.std(vals)
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(vals, mean, sd)
zScore = stats.zscore(vals)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(vals, pdf, c='b', marker='.')
ax.set_xlabel("vals", fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel("p", fontsize=10)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='0.5', linestyle='--')

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.plot(zScore, pdf, c='b', marker='.')
ax2.grid(b=True, which='major', color='r', linestyle='-')
ax2.set_xlabel("zScore", fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify, you want to fit a normal distribution to your X (`uniqueVals`) and Y (`occurrences`) values?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

As an idea:

```
#---- convert to integer ---
v    = np.array(uniqueVals,dtype=int)
occr = np.array(occurrences,dtype=int)

#---- we take smaller numbers for the example
v    = np.array([1,3,5])
occr = np.array([2,4,6])

#---- now we need the list again
vL = v.tolist()
oL = occr.tolist()

#----try this just to check
for v,o in zip(vL,oL):
    print([v]*o)

#---- now lets build the array
A = np.array([])
for v,o in zip(vL,oL):
    B = np.array([v]*o)
    A = np.r_[A,B].astype(int)
  
A
```

gives

```
[1, 1]
[3, 3, 3, 3]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
array([1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

Comment: Thanks but you're doing pretty much the same.